# Как настроить /64 подсеть?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

Мой хостинг провайдер (Vultr) дал мне /64 подсеть ipv6. При попытке запуска flask на на f0ca:9cee:7827:3ba9:: (первый адрес в /64 подсети) он выдает такую ошибку:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
Can't assign requested address
```

Если посмотреть ip адреса через `ip a`, то выдается всего один адрес (f0ca:9cee:7827:3ba9:94a9:68dc:defa:8b7c) из подсети, на котором flask не выдает ошибку.

Я так понял, что в сам сервер добавлен только один ipv6 адрес, а остальные надо добавлять вручную. За этим вопросом я полез в Google. Нашел [вот такую инструкцию](https://steemit.com/vultr/@manimj/add-additional-ipv6-on-vultr-vps), но она не помогла.

Как можно добавить еще один ipv6 адрес из подсети на сервер?